# bootstrap col resize next to each other when smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a responsive web-layout like : [image: regular size]

Upon resizing I would want the skills to be next to one another underneath the intro: [image]

**The problem** is mainly at the **intro** and **skill** boxes, I can't seem to get them to adjust the way I want: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/20858/

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">HEAD</div>     
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      INTRO
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      <div class="col m-0">SKILLS</div>
      <div class="col m-0">SKILLS</div>
      <div class="col m-0">SKILLS</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      EDUCATION
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      EXPERIENCE
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">OTHER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin:10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  margin: 10px;
}

.row, .col {
   min-width: 120px;
}
```

They keep setting underneath each other *which i only want when the screen is* extra **small**. this is simple but i just cant figure it out...

**I tried** adding `col-4` for intro (since intro should expand wider than skill) and messed with the columns more on the skill box to no luck..

Comment: you can try to use col-xs

Comment: You can do this with bootstrap 4 using the grid layout and flex - GRID https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ - FLEX https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: The added CSS is breaking the Bootstrap grid. You shouldn't change margins, min-width, etc.. on the row and cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues that are preventing you from getting the desired layout:

- `cols` must be the immediate child of a `row` ... the skills need to be wrapped in another row.
- Use `col-sm` to allow columns to stack vertically on the smaller layout.
- Don't adjust margins on the rows or cols as it will break the way the grid works.

Working demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/0g48AjUW4E

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-0 text-center">HEAD</div>     
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm p-0">
      INTRO
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto p-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col col-sm col-md-12">SKILLS</div>
          <div class="col col-sm col-md-12">SKILLS</div>
          <div class="col col-sm col-md-12">SKILLS</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-0">
      ED
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      EXPERIENCE
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-0">OTHER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col,.col-sm {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

Comment: It is indeed the one i was looking for, im unsure why it was downvoted so was my post, i guess salty stackoverflow users, its not my vote anyways, ill test it out and upvote it later

Answer (score 0):

First, when you separate into multiple cols you should wrap them inside a `row` ( so you have `display:flex` )

Second, you need to add classes to your columns to set how you want them to appear on different screen sizes. Note that as of bootstrap4 `col-xs` does not exist. Use `col` simple instead and overwrite it on larger screens.

In the example below i have used:

`col-lg-8` and `col-12` on the `INTRO` section.

`col-lg-4` and `col-12` on the `Skills` column wrapper.

`col-lg-12` and `col-4` on the `Skills` columns.

Also added a row to wrap the `Skills` columns

See below or [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/20860/)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin: 10px;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}

.row,
[class*="col-"] {
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">HEAD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-12">
      INTRO
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 p-0">
      <div class="row mx-0">


        <div class="col-lg-12 col-4 m-0">SKILLS</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-4 m-0">SKILLS</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-4 m-0">SKILLS</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      EDUCATION
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      EXPERIENCE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">OTHER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to wrap `skill` boxes in a `div` and give it classes `d-flex
  flex-wrap`
- By doing this, you will get the result without giving negative margin
- `col-md-8 col-sm-12` classes in `intro` div will make it `100%` for
  smaller device
- No need to make any `css` changes

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin:10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  margin: 10px;
}

.row, .col {
   min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">HEAD</div>     
  </div>
  
  <!-- Changes here -->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        INTRO
      </div>
      <div class="col p-0">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div class="col-4 col-md-12 m-0">SKILLS</div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-12 m-0">SKILLS</div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-12 m-0">SKILLS</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <!-- Changes Ends here --> 
   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      EDUCATION
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      EXPERIENCE
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">OTHER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest, but why is the intro box inconsistently bigger than other boxes, why is that? Using Col on it seems to fix it but messes up the resizing + how do i get the skills to go underneath each other if the screen is too small? Quite like the education and experience boxes are working

Comment: This happen because of the `bootstrap`. We need to follow it's grid structure to achieve our layout @Shayer

Answer (score -1):

I would use a media query for this. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

That is, keep your layout how you want it now as it is, then in the media query, just rearrange the layout to what you want it become on screen re-size.

Comment: why use media queries when he uses bootstrap ?